# Laravel Eloquent Notification value incorrect

Tags: laravel, email, notifications, eloquent

I'm using Laravel's notifications to email users when an article of theirs has been 'liked'.

The problem I'm having is when the user receives the email, the counted likes value is wrong (it's one too low).

So for example, a post has 2 likes, a user likes it, the post now has 3 likes, but the email the receives states that post has 2 likes.

Is this because the notification is fired before the data has had chance to save to the database?

Article->likes():

```
/**
 * Article morphs many Like.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
 */
 public function likes( )
 {
    // morphMany(MorphedModel, morphableName, type = able_type, relatedKeyName = able_id, localKey = id)
    return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable');
 }
```

When an article is Liked.... 
(LikeController)

```
public function getLikeArticle($id)
{

    $blog = Article::findOrFail($id);

    if(Auth::user()->hasLikedArticle($blog))
    {

        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->with('info-error', 'You have already liked that Post.');


    }

    $like = $blog->likes()->create([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);
    Auth::user()->likes()->save($like);


    $user = $blog->user;

    if(Auth::user()->id !== $user->id)
    {
        $user->notify(new UserLikedArticle($blog, Auth::user()));
    }

    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('info-success', 'Success, you like this');
}
```

Notification class (most of it)

```
use App\Models\Article\Article;
use App\Models\User\User;

class UserLikedArticle extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $article;
    protected $author;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Article $article, User $author)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
        $this->author = $author;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail', 'broadcast', 'database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)->markdown('email.notification.like.article', ['author' => $this->author, 'article' => $this->article]);
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the whole method in LikeController?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the original post to show the full function involved

Comment: thanks bro :). run return()->markdown().. return()->view() not run me.